# Vue 3, HERE Maps: Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'Worker': [object Array] could not be cloned

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, here-api

So we are migrating our code base from Vue 2 to Vue 3 and everything works fine for HERE maps except for the `.addObject()` event that keeps failing with the error:

> Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'Worker': [object Array] could not be cloned

Nothing else has been changed and the data exists and is properly formatted.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that Vue 3 uses Proxy and because of this, HERE maps throws a fit.

To fix this I used: `toRaw()` and wrapped the data inside of this! This fixed the issue.

Docs: https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-advanced.html#toraw